# SwiftUI: Converting UserDefault Slider Value (Double) to an Int within a String?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm having trouble with passing in the value of my slider into a string as Int when using User Defaults.
***Does anybody have a solution for converting my UserDefault value into my string?***

The following works just fine with a basic variable ([Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J14hL.png)):

```
    @State var Limit: Double = 8

var body: some View {
    Form {

        // Notification Limit
        Section (header: Text("NOTIFICATION LIMIT")) {
            HStack {
                Slider(value: $Limit, in: 1...15, step: 1.0)
                Text("\(Int(Limit))")
            }
        }
```

However, when I bring UserDefault Values into play, I recieve the following error:
***Initializer 'init(:)' requires that 'Binding< Double >' conform to 'BinaryInteger'***

```
    @ObservedObject var settings = notificationSettings()

var body: some View {
    Form {

        // Notification Limit
        Section (header: Text("NOTIFICATION LIMIT")) {
            HStack {
                Slider(value: $settings.globalLimit, in: 1...15, step: 1.0)
                Text("\(Int($settings.globalLimit))")
            }
        }
```

Leaving '$settings.globalLimit' as just double in the Text String gives the following error: ***Instance method 'appendInterpolation' requires that 'Binding< Double >' conform to 'FormatSpecifiable'***

Here's my full code currently for my 'globalSettingsView':

```
struct globalSettings: View {

@ObservedObject var settings = notificationSettings()

var body: some View {
    Form {
        // On/Off Toggle
        Toggle(isOn: $settings.globalOn) {
            Text("Notifications On/Off")
        }

        // Notification Limit
        Section (header: Text("NOTIFICATION LIMIT")) {
            HStack {
                Slider(value: $settings.globalLimit, in: 1...15, step: 1.0)
                Text("\(Int($settings.globalLimit))")
            }
        }

        // Time Range
        Section (header: Text("TIME RANGE")) {
            DatePicker("Start Time", selection: $settings.startTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            DatePicker("End Time", selection: $settings.endTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
        }

        // Notification Limit
        Section (header: Text("HELP")) {
            NavigationLink(destination: howToUse()) {
                Text("How To Use")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: reportFeedback()) {
                Text("Report Feedback")

            }
            Text("Ratings & Review")
            Text("Credits")
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Settings")

}
```

And the 'notificationSettings' class that holds the userDefaults:

```
class notificationSettings: ObservableObject {

// Variable Declarations
@Published var globalOn: Bool {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(globalOn, forKey: "globalOn")
    }
}
@Published var globalLimit: Double {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(globalLimit, forKey: "globalLimit")
    }
}
@Published var startTime: Date {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(startTime, forKey: "startTime")
    }
}
@Published var endTime: Date {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(endTime, forKey: "endTime")
    }
}

// Intialization
init() {
    self.globalOn = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "globalOn") as? Bool ?? true
    self.globalLimit = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "globalLimit") as? Double ?? 8.0
    self.startTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "startTime") as? Date ?? Date()
    self.endTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "endTime") as? Date ?? Date()

}
```

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't use binding ($) in `Text`, it shows value, not change it

```
Slider(value: $settings.globalLimit, in: 1...15, step: 1.0)
Text("\(Int(settings.globalLimit))")          // << here !!
```

Comment: Lol. I can't believe I missed that! Thanks a bunch.